# FireFox не сохраняет *.exe при скачивании

Tags: firefox

Самый мой любимый браузер перестал или с какой-то версии разучился(разучили) сохранять *.exe фалы.
Остался после работы, 1,5 часа ждал закачки 400 мб!
И по завершении файла просто не стало!
(Все остальные браузеры скачивают данное расширение и сохраняют его нормально.)
Точно не антивирус, так как этот же файл, другие сохраняют нормально и без всяких эксцессов.

---

P.S. FireFox - убогая бродилка, не умеющая сохранять файлы *.exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант сделать about:config → browser.download.manager.scanWhenDone = false

И еще создать новый профиль, часто у ФФ с профилями бывают бока.

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Большое! Помогло!